# unable to sign in user! firebase/flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to flutter and Firebase !
been trying to set up authentication but my login doesn't work!
user gets to see home screen when the app launches and I have two buttons witch navigates to sign in and signup, the sign up works perfectly and redirect users to the new screen while the sign in does say in the (console) that everything is well but doesn't navigate!

This my authservice:

```
  class AuthService {
   static final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
   static final _firestore = Firestore.instance;




  static void signUpUser(
      BuildContext context, String name, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      FirebaseUser signedInUser = authResult.user;

      if (signedInUser != null) {
        _firestore.collection('/users').document(signedInUser.uid).setData({
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'profileImageUrl': '',
        });
        Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId =
            signedInUser.uid;

        Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
//        Navigator.pop(context);
      }

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static void login(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

   static void logout() {
    _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

This is the signup submit button:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _name, _email, _password;

  _submit() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      AuthService.signUpUser(context, _name, _email, _password);
    }
  }
```

And this is the login:

```
 _submit() {
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      AuthService.login(_email, _password);

    }
  }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting in console? May i see your console screenshot?

Comment: Hey you have forgot to add your navigate to home page code  i saw your code, look at your login method

Comment: `Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id); `

Comment: im not able to add Navigator.pushNamed(context, YourLoginPageName.id); inside the method! i get redlines under CONTEXT and dart analys says undefined name context!

Comment: i tried navigating through  _submit() but then it navigates even though the user dosent exist! thanks every body btw

Comment: @ErrorPlace you have to handle `if-else` logic in login method.

Comment: You should add navigation code into try block of login method of AuthService class like you have done with signUpUser method

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this in login method.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, YourLoginPageName.id);
```

Comment: im not able to add Navigator.pushNamed(context, YourLoginPageName.id); inside the method! i get redlines under CONTEXT and dart analys says undefined name context!

Comment: just pass the context to login like how you did in signUp method.